# How do I hide-unhide "View" element within View Controller with a button click? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a View Controller that contains two buttons and their respective dropdown menus ("View" elements). How do I hide/unhide these view elements? What is the code required?

Comment: someView.hidden = YES;

Answer (score 1):

You can set the hidden property as Sergey suggested :

```
view.hidden = YES;
view.hidden = NO;
```

or by calling the method setHidden:

```
[view setHidden:YES];
[view setHidden:NO];
```

You can also play with the alpha property of the view to make it more transparent or not. Keep in mind that the view are still "present" in this case.

```
view.alpha = 0.0f;
[view setAlpha:0.0f];
```

**EDIT after more precisions from author :**

```
[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(myAction) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This is how you make your button "listen" for events and do specific actions. 
You can create a Boolean property in your viewController, for example _isShown.

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{
   //Write the hide/show code here
   if (_isShown) {
     // hide view code
     _isShown = NO;
   } else {
     // show view code
     _isShown = YES;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean on a button touch. So if touched: its shown - if it's touched again - its hidden and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (different from the obvious hide property) is to also shrink the height(or width) to 0. Here's an example:

```
CGFloat viewHeight = myView.hidden == 0 ? 100 : 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    myView.hidden = !myView.hidden;
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y, CGRectGetWidth(myView.frame), viewHeight);
}];
```